# Сохранение изменений в List

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте.

Как можно сохранить изменения, сохраненные в `List2` (содержит измененные данные), в `List1` (первоначальный список)?

P.S. Заранее извините за криво поставленный вопрос.

Comment: >Заранее извините за криво поставленный вопрос.

так задайте не криво

Comment: Хочу попробовать реализовать сохранение изменений с возможностью отмены(при нажатии кнопки отмена), по аналогии с редактированием DataGrid(исходные данные - редактируемая копия).

Comment: А чем вам очевидное `List1 = List2;` не угодило?

Comment: Наверно я не понимаю как это реализовать, но идея заключается в том, что в List1 надо заменить измененный записи(хранящиеся в List2), при этом не попортив первоначальный List1. Вариант с "List1 = new List(List2);" вроде как должен затереть все записи в List1 и вписать записи из List2. Сделать это циклом можно, но в целях проверки скорости работы кода ищу решение средствами функций.

Comment: @Pac: Стоп. У вас **элементы** списка редактировались, или добавлялись новые/уходили старые? В первом случае, очевидно, вообще ничего не надо делать, т. к. список содержит лишь ссылки. (Убедитесь, что вы осознали это.) Во втором случае `List1 = List2` решает.

Answer (score 2):

```
List1 = new List(List2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант решения возможности отмены:

1. List1 - рабочий список, в котором производятся изменения
2. Array1 - массив с произведенными над списком действиями (возможно с обратным смыслом)

   - Добавление элемента списка (в массиве может храниться как Удаление элемента, подразумевает добавление либо в начало списка, либо в конец)
   - Вставка элемента (аналогично Добавлению, но подразумевает определенную позицию в списке)
   - Редактирование элемента (должно запомниться, кроме позиции элемента, его состояние до редактирования)
   - и т.д.

В любом случае более конкретно можно говорить зная больше о предметной области применения списке. Если список текстовый, ну или список однотипных объектов с фиксированным набором свойств, то достаточно будет приведенного подхода. А если список произвольных объектов или объектов с переменной структурой, то тут реализация будет посложнее, но принцип в общем-то сохранится.

Пример в тему задачи - [Реализация операции отмены с обеспечением безопасности данных](http://jenyay.net/Programming/UndoRedo).

Comment: Боже, зачем всё так сложно?

Кстати, вы спутали C# и javascript.

Comment: Я привел пример. Не думаю что принцип не применим к какому-то языку... Тем более что C# есть практически клон JS ;)  
Но пример копирования объекта убрал, раз он так вам мозолит глаза. Добавил пример для C# с отменой/повтором действий.

Comment: @t1nk: угу. только зачем массив? в него ж элемент невозможно добавить (в C#).

Comment: > только зачем массив? в него элемент невозможно добавить (в C#).  
Простите не понял вашей шутки...  
Массивы для того и предназначены что бы хранить элементы.  
Если не нравится конкретно массив можете использовать что-то, смысл тот же - создание стека или буфера для хранения действий и состояния элементов связанных с ними.

Comment: @t1nk,  
 
     Массивы для того и предназначены что бы хранить элементы.   

Так то оно да. Но они предназначены, чтобы хранить неизменное количество элементов данных. Можно, конечно использовать Array.Resize, но зачем, если есть List<>?

Comment: @teanЫЧ: При этом, `Array.Resize` создаёт новый массив, а те, у кого осталась ссылка на старый, проиграли. В отличие от `List`, который меняет размер in-place.

В общем, с массивами тот ещё геморрой.